# invalid date format in javascript

Tags: javascript, angularjs

I am getting invalid date for one date and other date is working fine, what is the problem in this.

```
var checkinStartDate=new Date("10/07/2016 09:10:04 AM")
working fine

var checkinEndDate = new Date("10/07/2016 19:10:04 PM") 
getting invalid date
```

Comment: Am/pm is a 12 hour format and you've passed 19 as the hour. 19=7pm.

Comment: There's no 19 PM...

Comment: How did you got the second date? You probably need to fix the source who generated this date

Comment: your second date is not correct you have used 19 as hours and when ever you have put PM. so if you want to use am/pm than use time 12 hours formate not in 24 hours formate

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It should be like:

```
var checkinEndDate = new Date("10/07/2016 07:10:04 PM")
```

`19:10:04 PM` There are no AM/PM in 24 hr time format